# find a combination of numbers that equal a given sum from a single column in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL table packages which has fields `id, max_post`. Values in max_post contains

```
  1,2,3,4,5,10,20,30,40,50,100,200,500,1000,2000
```

I want to find best fit package. For example, I enter 230, then it should
eliminate everything and select the 200 and the 30 packages. I want to get result using SQL query.

Comment: Your example suggests that `230` should correspond to *only* `200,30`, but what about `200,20,10`?  Are you expressly looking for the smallest list?  And what about the value `7` which can be made from `5,2` or `4,3`?

Comment: Or the value `483`?  `1,2,3,4,5,10,20,30,40,50,100,200` = 465, the next possible value being `500`; do you choose `500` for being the closest, or `1,2,3,4,5,10,20,30,40,50,100,200` for being the largest possible value that is less than or equal to your target?  Or can you use one number multiple times to make a list that adds up to exactly 465?

Comment: Maximum number in a combination is 3 or 4 and repetition is not possible.

Comment: What about all the other ambiguities mentioned?  Does `230` = `200,20,10` as well as `200,30`, and if not what rules should be used to pick one possible match from the list of all matches?  Does `7` = `5,2` or `4,3` or both?  Does `483` = `200,100,50,40` or `500`?

Comment: least count combination . ie,200,30. If  more than one combination takeing any one. For 483 , we choose 200,100,50,40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a corrected version of Gordon's query. Mainly Gordon's query lacks joining a null record when there is a smaller value available. The best match it finds for 230 is 200-20-5-4, because the best solution 200-30-null-null is not even in the set we are evaluating. This is because p3 is never actually outer-joined to 200-30, as there are records with a smaller value than 30 in the table. (To outer-join means add a null record when there is *no* match.)

```
select 
  p1.max_post, p2.max_post, p3.max_post, p4.max_post
from packages p1 
left join (select max_post from packages union all select null) p2
  on (p1.max_post > p2.max_post or p2.max_post is null)  
left join (select max_post from packages union all select null) p3 
  on (p2.max_post > p3.max_post or p3.max_post is null)  
left join (select max_post from packages union all select null) p4 
  on (p3.max_post > p4.max_post or p4.max_post is null)  
where p1.max_post + coalesce(p2.max_post, 0) + coalesce(p3.max_post, 0) + coalesce(p4.max_post, 0) <= 230
order by 
  p1.max_post + coalesce(p2.max_post, 0) + coalesce(p3.max_post, 0) + coalesce(p4.max_post, 0) desc,
  (p2.max_post is null) desc,
  (p3.max_post is null) desc,
  (p4.max_post is null) desc
limit 1;
```

(This can be slightly optimised by adding `where max_post <= 230` to the queries, so records with a value that itself is already higher then the desired sum, will be dismissed immediately.)

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f6d25/18.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a bin-packing problem.  Basically, the only way to solve it is explicitly.

You can get the list of all such combinations by doing explicit joins:

```
select p1.max_post, p2.max_post, p3.max_post, p4.max_post
from packages p1 left join
     packages p2
     on p1.max_post > p2.max_post left join
     packages p3
     on p2.max_post > p3.max_post left join
     packages p4
     on p3.max_post > p4.max_post
where (p1.max_post + coalesce(p2.max_post, 0) + coalesce(p3.max_post, 0) +
       coalesce(p4.max_post, 0)
      ) = 230
order by (p2.max_post is null) desc,
         (p3.max_post is null) desc,
         (p4.max_post is null) desc
```

The `order by` puts the "shorter" lists first.  You can add a `limit` if you like.

Note:  this is essentially creating a Cartesian product among the values in the table four times.  As the size of the tables grows, the time for execution will also grow.

Comment: Won't solve `483` => `200,100,50,40`; in its current form.

Comment: I like this straight-forward solution. There is a small error considering how outer joins work in the query, though. I've added a separate answer, because I find the issue rather hard to explain in a comment.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . . . Your solution is better for up-to-4 numbers.  I was really thinking exactly-4-numbers and should not have included the `left join`s in the query.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that will meet you stated preference that `483` => `200,100,50,40`

```
SELECT
    target.max_post,
    p1.id,
    p1.max_post,
    p2.id,
    p2.max_post,
    p3.id,
    p3.max_post,
    p4.id,
    p4.max_post
FROM
(
    SELECT 483 AS max_post
)
    target
LEFT JOIN
    packages p1
        ON  p1.id = (SELECT id
                       FROM packages
                      WHERE max_post <= target.max_post
                   ORDER BY max_post DESC
                      LIMIT 1
                    )
LEFT JOIN
    packages p2
        ON  p2.id = (SELECT id
                       FROM packages
                      WHERE max_post <= target.max_post - p1.max_post
                   ORDER BY max_post DESC
                      LIMIT 1
                    )
LEFT JOIN
    packages p3
        ON  p3.id = (SELECT id
                       FROM packages
                      WHERE max_post <= target.max_post - p1.max_post - p2.max_post
                   ORDER BY max_post DESC
                      LIMIT 1
                    )
LEFT JOIN
    packages p4
        ON  p4.id = (SELECT id
                       FROM packages
                      WHERE max_post <= target.max_post - p1.max_post - p2.max_post - p3.max_post
                   ORDER BY max_post DESC
                      LIMIT 1
                    )
```

It uses repeated correlated sub-queries.  For very small `packages` tables the Cartesian Product search *may* be faster *(though not solve the case mentioned above)*, for anything of any reasonable size I'd expect the correlated sub-queries to be faster.

For a table of 10 values
 - the Cartesian Product searches many hundreds of combinations *(much more than `10 choose 4` = `210`)*
 - the Correlated Sub-Queries search 40 values *(10x4)*

For a table of 100 values
 - the Cartessian Product searches many millions of combinations *(much more than `100 choose 4` = `3,921,225`)*
 - the Correlated Sub-Queries search 400 values *(100x4)*

Comment: This is a good idea. (You should add criteria not to pick the same value twice, however, which is quickly done.) But one has to keep in mind that this query depends on the data set, because it always takes the maximum value that still fits in the sum. For instance it works with the set given, but would not find the best solution for 60, if 10 were missing from the set. (It would pick 50 first, then end up with 50-5-4-1, rather then simply picking 40-20.)